# Multiprocessing taking unusual time for a simple function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing. But the main problem is it is taking time to return values for a simple function.

The code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x

p = Pool(3)
```

The main time consuming part is when I am calling the map function of Pool.

```
p.map(f,[1,2,3])
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: For such a simple function, the time will be completely dominated by creating, starting and stopping the processes. If instead, you were to get `f()` to perform some heavily cpu intensive work, like finding prime numbers, the task might start to dominate instead,

Comment: How are you timing this, how is it compared to non-parallel code, and why are you parallelizing this function? As explained above there is only loss when trying to parallelize simple functions as the overhead shadows the performance gain

Answer (score -1):

I have customized your program to calculate time for different argument count and you could observe that for values [1,2,3], the execution time is less when compared to [1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Please note that these values will not be consistent as the number of args are really less for measurement and observation.

Here is the code.

```
def f(x):
  return x

Init_time = time.time()
p = Pool(3)
p.map(f,[1,2,3,4,5,6])
End_time = time.time()
print("%s seconds" % (End_time - Init_time))



#---0.0783853530883789   seconds ---
#---0.08818411827087402  seconds ---
#---0.0620882511138916   seconds -- . This is for [1,2,3]
#---0.08222532272338867  seconds ---
#---0.06706833839416504  seconds ---
#---0.08183670043945312  seconds ---
```